# When is Shorthand allowed in functions?

Tags: javascript, syntax, shortcut

I see great help examples on this site all the time and have always been curious about the following example. I searched this site for short hand examples and couldn't find the exact explanation to the below type syntax.

I have pasted this code into my site and it does exactly what I wanted it to do, but when coders use short-cuts it never quit clicks with me because I don't know the short cuts.

The actual functionality of the function is not as relevant, but for clarity, all I wanted to do was search the current URL with javascript for the presence of a particular GET variable and then react to its contents or lack of presence.

Please don't try and solve this equation with a more elegant function. I am currently asking exactly HOW THE BELOW function actually solved my question based on its particular syntax. I never understand unless the full versions are type all the way out with no short cuts or short-hand.

What is the following function, which uses short-hand and short-cuts (the one I pasted from this site and worked) actually saying in long hand?

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = "nope",
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}
```

When I tried to re-write it so I could understand I broke it of course. I assume the comma at the start is the key, because what I re-wrote looked like the below and DID NOT WORK.

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = "nope";
    tmp = [];
    location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function (item) {
        tmp = item.split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]); 
    });
    return result;
}
```

I am confused when the variable "result" gets changed to the value that is calculated by the actual function. Does the comma do that in the first line of the pasted way above my broken re-write?

Often I try to rewrite code I pasted from this site and it always breaks it!! hahah. So I sometimes don't actually LEARN how I solved it, rather I learn that I can copy and paste from StackOverflow and solve it. hahaha. THANK THE LORD for you all!

What seems like the way I would do this example above is much longer and probably why coders avoid doing it this way, but I can't wrap my head around the syntax that allows for the above example.

My gut tells me to do something like the below?

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = "nope";
    var tmp = new Array();
    tmp = [];
    
    var location_search = "";
    location_search = location.search.substr(1);

    var location_search_split = "";
    location_search_split = location_search.split("&");

    forEach( /* SUPER LOST HERE! hahahah */ function (item) {
    /* I assume this a short cut to do something like PHP version of */
    /* foreach( location_search_split as $key=>$value ) ???? */

    tmp = item.split("=");
    if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    
    result = ????? // WHEN does the function set the value of the RESULT variable?
    });
    
    return result;
}
```

I love this site and have gotten so much over the years from it. I am a very amateur hack of a coder and use this site millions of times a year. You guys are all awesome and I love reading through to find the stuff because I know one of you will always solve it!

But I truly am an amateur and just tired of not seeing the short-hand better!

THANKS for your patience ahead of time with your answers not making too much fun of me. If you saw some of what I've been able to get accomplished with javascript/php/jquery over the years you'd be more impressed at my ingenuity than unimpressed with my naiveness!! hahahah. But sometimes I feel like I am producing Star Wars with iMOVIE 1.0.

Comment: I am a bit lost here, is the question is when to use shorthand and when not to use?

Comment: SO is not a blog/forum, It not shorthand, it looks like normal js, in js return values can be chained because of prototyping on the data types, i.e a returned String has all String prototype functions attached to it. And your right forEach loops over the iterable items, one could change it to a for of loop, but the entire findGetParameter function should be changed to use a couple of lines [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) or [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Your first and second snippets are pretty much equivalent, the only difference is that the second assigns to a *global* `tmp` variable (missing the `var` declaration). It should still work however. What error are you getting? What input leads to a difference result?

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is the line that causes me trouble each time I see it. // if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]); // without the braces I never trust what it will give me back without knowing the structure of the shorthand. Possibly when I retyped here I didn't paste the non-working version of my retype and accidentally typed something that would actually work. In trying to divide the short-hand up I added semi-colon before the result I think and it just kept giving me problems. But to Ranjit, YES, I would love to know when to and not to use short hand.